# Smooth vs topological orientation

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I am confused about the different notions for a closed smooth manifold to be oriented.  In my mind there are several equivalent ones:

1) Coherent pointwise orientation of the tangent spaces.

2) Choice of nonvanishing top dimensional form.

3) Orientation of the top dimensional de Rham cohomology group as a real vector space.

I understand the equivalence of these above notions.  There are also some similar definitions for an orientation of a topological manifold:

1) Coherent choice of generators for the pointwise homology groups $H_n(M, M \setminus \{x\}; \mathbb{Z})$.

2) Choice of generator ("fundamental class") for the top homology group $H_n(M; \mathbb{Z})$.

My question is the following: how does a choice of smooth orientation induce a choice of topological orientation?

Thanks!

Comment: Potentially helpful: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Orientation_of_manifolds

Comment: You should ask yourself when you consider two orientations to be the same. It's not true that a top form induces a fundamental class in _integral_ (co)homology, but it is true up to scale in an appropriate sense.